# Android: stopping a service on activity not responding

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I am developing an FMR application which consists of a Radio Activity class and a RadioService Service class, the latter being the link between the app and the FM framework.

When the activity has been launched and tuning has been done, if the back button is pressed, the activity's onStop() and onDestroy() methods are called. In the latter, the activity **just unbinds from the service** which continues to play the radio.

At times however, the activity blocks and becomes unresponsive in which case, the **ANR ( Activity not responding )** comes up. If the user "force close"s the activity, the radio service is still running in the background and the sound output can be heard. **Ideally, on force close, the expected behaviour should be to stop the service from playing.**

Is there any method for the activity to know that an ANR has occured and it's being "force closed", so that it can signal the radio service to stop playing?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dev

Comment: It looks like you already have a lead. What about trying that FIRST and then asking?

Comment: hmm would check in the service for the Apps PID

Comment: Tried putting some messages and disabling the service in onServiceDisconnected() but adb logcat shows that it is not called during force close. Used Settings-Applications->Running for force stopping

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?